# Getting the remainder of a stringstream c++

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have a stringstream where I need to get the first part out and then get the remainder into a separate string. For example I have the string `"This is a car"` and I need to end up with 2 strings: `a = "This"` and `b = "is a car"`.

When I use stringstream to get the first part using `<<`,then I use the `.str()` to convert to a string which of course gave me the whole thing "`This is a car"`. How can I get it to play how I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string str = "this is a car";

std::stringstream ss;
ss << str;

string a,b;
ss >> a;
getline(ss, b);
```

**EDIT:** correction thanks to @Cubbi:

```
ss >> a >> ws;
```

**EDIT:**

This solution can handle newlines in some cases (such as my test cases) but fails in others (such as @rubenvb's example), and I haven't found a clean way to fix it. **I think @tacp's solution is better, more robust, and should be accepted.**

Comment: That makes b `" is a car"`, to make it `"is a car"`, how about `ss >> a >> ws;` ?

Comment: Thanks, I used string.erase(0, 1) to get rid of the space.

Comment: @Cubbi: Good point, but your solution assumes exactly one character of whitespace. I'd feel safer with something like `b.erase(0,b.find_first_not_of("..."))`.

Comment: @Beta `std::ws` consumes all whitespace.

Comment: @Cubbi: **Damn! I did not know that.**

Comment: This solution fails if the string contains a newline. And you don't even check for failure.

Comment: @rubenvb: With Cubbi's correction, it doesn't fail if the string contains a newline (or multiple newlines).

Comment: This still fails with newlines. Example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d934749f40bc987d7808fc14d9ac25fb-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba). Granted though, handling newlines was not part of the question. But it might not be obvious what the `getline` here does to the uneducated reader.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this: first get the whole string, then get the first word, using `substr` to get the rest.

```
 stringstream s("This is a car");
 string s1 = s.str();
 string first;
 string second;

 s >> first;
 second = s1.substr(first.length());
 cout << "first part: " << first <<"\ second part: " << second <<endl;
```

Testing this in gcc 4.5.3 outputs:

```
first part: This 
second part: is a car
```

Comment: Worth noting that this won't work if the original string was actually `" This is a car "`

Comment: you can also do that without the variable s1, just do s.str().substr(first.length());

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `getline` on the stream after reading out the first bit....

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with rdbuf:

```
stringstream s("This is a car");
string first;
stringstream second;

s >> first;
second << s.rdbuf();
cout << "first part: " << first << " second part: " << second.str() << endl;
```

This may be a good option if you're ultimately going to output the result to a stream instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str = "This is a car";

std::stringstream ss;
ss << str;

std::string start;
ss >> start;
std::string remaining = ss.str().substr(ss.tellg());
```